# Building Android Loading Dialog Box with AIR

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, air-native-extension

I am starting to develop android applications using AS3.

As much as I've searched I did not find how to make android loading box using AIR!

It seems there is no way to do so!

Can anybody help me in this regard please?!

Comment: What is an "Android loading box" Oo ?

Comment: It is a Show by which you can display the process of loading, downloading, uploading or something like these...!

Comment: So basically, we are talking about a panel, with a spinner and the text "loading".... Why don´t you just build it, if you need it?

Comment: No, because this is simply a box. This has nothing to do with Java or not Java. Simply build in in AIR.

Comment: I don't know maybe I can not really explain what I want. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kindly beg you to search more and more. Your topic is a rare and helpful one I also appreciate that but I think you just need to increase your Googling Abilities :D

I guess I know what you were searching for so I just searched about your topic and the result is exactly what you need I am sure.

You know,, you can not access android device-specific libraries and features with AS3 for these are not available in the built-in AS3 classes. There are some air extensions provided to help us the air developers who want to make Android or iOS apps though.

Am I clear enough? if not go to this link please. Here you can learn more and even use some extensions in your projects if necessary: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html

And a happy link for you and your topic:
http://www.myappsnippet.com/loading-dialog-air-extension

Just tell me if this is what you wanted. I'll be happy!

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly standard and has been covered here a few times. Like this for example.

[as3 loading screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440474/as3-loading-screen)
or this ROC tutorial
[as3 preloader](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3preloader/)

U basically calculate the current percentage in a progress event and change a bar's width or scale accordingly.