# Convert Flash website from AS2 to AS3 using the code below, how do I get the preloader to stop and load as requested?

Tags: actionscript-3, html5-canvas

Below is AS2 attempt to convert to AS3. The comment sections have the AS2, while I have tried to change to AS3. I am picking up the skill after a few years. I wanted to share this code to verify what I am doing is correct. If not, what can I do differently? Not too good on the math side of things so it becomes intimidating sometimes. Does the ENTER_FRAME need to be specified somehow? Any assistance and advice would be great!

This project is a flash website written in AS2. I started learning AS3 when CS5 came out. I don't mind doing the parts that looks repeated. Please verify the code is correct.

```
    import flash.display.Loader;

    //Calculates the amount to load and how much is loaded
    /*AS2.0 script: 
    percentLoaded = Math.round(root.getBytesLoaded() / root.getBytesTotal() * 100);*/

    var percentloaded:Number = load/total * 100;
    var myWidth:Number = this.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
    var myMove:Number = this.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;

    //Sets the width of the bar
    /*AS2.0 script: 
    this.myWidth(this.loadBar, percentLoaded * 2);
    this.myMove(this.mc_loadNum, percentLoaded * 2 );
    loadNum.text = percentLoaded +"%";
    */

    percentLoaded = loadBar(percentage*100);
    LoadBar.Scalex = percentage;

    var loadBar: Number = percentLoaded *2;
    var mc_loadNum:Number = percentLoaded * 2;

    var loadNum.text = percentLoaded + "%";`

    // FUNCTIONS
    /*AS2.0 Scripts:
    function myWidth(moveObj, newWidth) {
        moveObj.w = moveObj._width;
        moveObj.dwidth = newWidth-moveObj.w;
        moveObj.t = 0;
        NFRAMES = 6; "<-- number of stops(); placed on frames"
        moveObj.onEnterFrame = function() {
            if (moveObj.t++<NFRAMES) {
                moveObj._width = easeOutQuad(moveObj.t, moveObj.w, moveObj.dwidth, 
    NFRAMES);
                } else {
                    delete this.onEnterFrame;
                }
           };
      }
    function myMove(moveObj, newX) {
        moveObj.x = moveObj._x;
        moveObj.dx = newX-moveObj.x;
        moveObj.t = 0;
        NFRAMES = 6;
        moveObj.onEnterFrame = function() {
            if (moveObj.t++<NFRAMES) {
                moveObj._x = easeOutQuad(moveObj.t, moveObj.x, moveObj.dx, NFRAMES);
            } else {
                delete this.onEnterFrame;
            }
       };
   }

    easeOutQuad = function (time, beginX, changeX, durationX) {
        if ((time /= durationX/2)<1) {
            return changeX/2*time*time+beginX;
        }
        return -changeX/2*((--time)*(time-2)-1)+beginX;
    };

    //FRAME2 | ACTIONS
            if (percentLoaded < 100 ) {
                gotoAndPlay("loading");
            }

    //FRAME3 | ACTIONS
            root.gotoAndPlay(48);

    */

    LoadBackground.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveObj);
    function moveObj(moveObj, newWidth) {
    var moveObj.w = moveObj.width;
    var moveObj.dwidth = newWidth - moveObj.w;
    var moveObj.t: Number = 0;
    var NFRAMES: Number = 6;
    moveObj.onEnterFrame = function () {
    if (moveObj.t++ < NFRAMES) {
        moveObj._width = easeOutQuad(moveObj.t, moveObj.w, moveObj.dwidth, NFRAMES);
    } else {
        delete this.onEnterFrame;
            }
        };
    }
    x.addEventListenter(Event.ENTER_FRAME, myMove);
    function myMove(Event.moveObj, newX) {
        moveObj.x = moveObj.x;
        moveObj.dx = newX - moveObj.x;
        moveObj.t = 0;
        NFRAMES = 6;
        moveObj.onEnterFrame = function () {
            if (moveObj.t++ <= NFRAMES) {
                moveObj.x = easeOutQuad(moveObj.t, moveObj.x, moveObj.dx, NFRAMES);
            } else {
                delete this.onEnterFrame;
            }
        };
    } 

    function easeOutQuad(time, beginX, changeX, durationX) {
        if ((time /= durationX / 2) < 1) {
            return changeX / 2 * time * time + beginX;
        }
        return -changeX / 2 * ((--time) * (time - 2) - 1) + beginX;
    }


    /*
    easeOutQuad = function (time, beginX, changeX, durationX) {
        if ((time /= durationX / 2) < 1) {
            return changeX / 2 * time * time + beginX;
        }
        return -changeX / 2 * ((--time) * (time - 2) - 1) + beginX;
    };
   */
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to **StackOverflow**. I think you should split your question into smaller problems and describe them as following: 1) This chunk of code should (short yet meaningful explanation). 2) AS2 script that does the thing. 3) AS3 script that seems to not. Because at the moment the provided code is (no offense) an incomprehensible mess, so even pointing out the obvious errors will probably not make the whole script work.

Comment: _"Does the ENTER_FRAME need to be specified somehow?"_ No you need a `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS` attached to the loader to know whenever these bytes are loaded (it will fire many times allowing your bar's width to increase). See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11440474/2057709 for answering _"How do I get the preloader to stop and load as requested?"_